# How get data from JSON file by readfile in Vue?

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, readfile

I can't read of JSON file content,
I tried to access the contents of the file by ReadFile but I did not success,
I get string empty for content and url is undefined,

My Code:

```
<template>
 <div class="large-12 medium-12 small-12 cell">
   <input type="file" accept="application/JSON" @change="onFileChange" class="inputFile" />
 </div>
</template>

<script>
import Vue from "vue";

export default {
 data() {
   return {};
 },
 methods: {
   onFileChange(e) {
     let files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;
     if (!files.length) return;
     this.readFile(files[0]);
   },
   readFile(file) {
     let reader = new FileReader();
     reader.onload = e => {
       this.readContentFile = e.target.result;
       console.log(this.readFile);
     };
     let url = reader.readAsDataURL(file);
     let content =reader.result;
     console.log(url);
     console.log(content);
   }
 }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You almost had it. reader.onload is like a callback for when file has finished loading, so your console.logs near the bottom would happen before the file has loaded. Hopefully you should find this snippet helpful.

```js
new Vue ({
 el: "#app",
 methods: {
   onFileChange(e) {
     let files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;
     if (!files.length) return;
     this.readFile(files[0]);
   },
   readFile(file) {
     let reader = new FileReader();
     reader.onload = e => {
       console.log(e.target.result);
       let json = JSON.parse(e.target.result);
     };
     reader.readAsText(file);
   }
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div class="large-12 medium-12 small-12 cell" id="app">
   <input type="file" accept="application/json" @change="onFileChange">
</div>
```